# Use CNTLM running on host system on hyper-v vm

Tags: proxy, ntlm, hyper-v, http-proxy

I have a windows 10 machine that is running a cntlm proxy on port 3128.
When starting a vm using hyper-v and a Virtual Switch configured with the external network setting.

[image: Virtual Switch configuration]

I can ping the host machine from the VM using its IP:

```
$ ping $hostIp
PING $hostIP ($hostIP): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from $hostIp: seq=0 ttl=128 time=1.480 ms
64 bytes from $hostIp: seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.893 ms
64 bytes from $hostIp: seq=2 ttl=128 time=1.179 ms
64 bytes from $hostIp: seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.997 ms
64 bytes from $hostIp: seq=4 ttl=128 time=1.318 ms
...
```

but I can't for example execute curl using this IP as proxy IP.

```
curl -x http://$hostIp:3128 https://google.de
```

On the host machine this command results in

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.de/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

On the VM this results in

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to $hostIp port 3128: Connection timed out
```